# pylint with jenkins - complince that can't find xml file

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest, pylint

I am trying to run pylint with jenkins with following command:

```
 pylint -f parseable -d I0011,R0801 "mypath\highLevel" | tee.exe pylint.out
```

The process looks run fine, pylint.out created with a lot of information inside but during pylint report creation I get following error:

```
13:38:27 ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsPublisher aborted due to exception
13:38:27 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\DMD\.jenkins\jobs\Diamond - Run Coverage\builds\2015-07-26_13-34-30\violations\file\A:\highLevel\Monitor\InitialBootAdapter.py.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

It's creates very strange path:

```
C:\Users\DMD\.jenkins\jobs\Diamond - Run Coverage\builds\2015-07-26_13-34-30\violations\file\A:\highLevel\Monitor\InitialBootAdapter.py.xml
```

I don't really understand what happens.
Why pylint is interested in file InitialBootAdapter.py? Why it's looks for file InitialBootAdapter.py.xml? Who should create it and why? I searched for this file over all the environment and didn't find. But I did'nt find any xml for my other py files?
Maybe you have experience with pylint and can help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem, it took time and DevOps help but it worked and is [described in my own blog](http://ingenuen.blogspot.co.il/2015/11/jenkins-violation-plugin-on-windows.html) (it's more my online notebook than blog) in very small details.

The most important point in this post is small utility

```
import fileinput, sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(sys.argv[1], inplace=True):
        if ".cs"  in line:
            line = line.replace("\\", "/")
        print line,
```

Here `sys.argv[1]`  should be path to your `violations.xml` file.
You have to move the path as a command line argument to the utility as path to your `violations.xml` file is dynamic and depends on build id.

Answer (score 8):

I have experience with pylint in jenkins. And here is how I use it, hope it will help someone.

**Step 1**
Add a "Execute Shell" step and execute the `pylint` command to generate the pylint.out. Please note

```
/usr/local/bin/pylint -f parseable -d I0011,R0801 my-python-project-folder | tee pylint.out
```

**Step 2**
Make sure you have the [Violation Report Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violation+Columns+Plugin), after that , click `Add post-build action`-->Report Violation, put the pylint.out in the corresponding field.
[image]

And after the successful run, the pylint report looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I did the same, but it didn't work too. Do you think this is difference how to run pylint? With power shell or regular command line? I think the problem is with wrong path creation:"C:\Users\DMD\.jenkins\jobs\Diamond - Run Coverage\builds\2015-07-26_13-34-30\violations\file\A:\highLevel\Monitor\InitialBootAdapter.py.xml". There are at least two pathes here.